# A question about my refrigerator

Tags: watts

it's written on my refrigerator 500watts..
I want to know how much it consume watts per month.
let's consider that the compressor of the refrigerator works 10 hrs per day.

Comment: "watts" is an instantaneous unit.  "watts per month" is meaningless.

Comment: Also, note that the rating is for continuous operation. But refrigerators (normally) don't run continuously. So your consumption will depend mostly on how warm your kitchen is, with more consumption at higher temperatures. A secondary effect is how often you open the door and let the cold air out. The short answer is that you can't calculate it - you need to measure it.

Comment: In the US, refrigerators sold / on display in stores are required to have a sticker on them giving this type of information, which includes more data sources than you provided.  Typically there's some sort of yearly power consumption, estimated power cost, and a comparison to an average of similar sized models.

Comment: yes exactly..thats why I said consider that the compressor of the refrigerator works 10 hours pre day,since it's not working continuously and also depends on the temperature and the space around

Answer (score 1):

You are billed in kilowatt-hours (kWh).

Energy used (kWh) = power (kW) x time (h).

- 500 W = 0.5 kW.
- 0.5 kW x 10 h = 5 kWh per day.

You should be able to calculate the monthly energy use.